# Finding the constant in Stolz region

Tags: complex-analysis

Given two points $z_1, z_2 \in \mathbb{C}$ such that $|z_1| < 1$ and $|z_2|<1$, there exists $K > 0$ such that for any points $z \neq 1$ in the closed triangle with vertices $z_1, z_2,$ and 1,
$$\frac{|1-z|}{1-|z|} \leq K.$$
Find the smallest possible value of $K$ if $z_1 = \frac{1+i}{2}, z_2 = \frac{1-i}{2}.$

I let $z = x + iy$ in the closed triangle and use two dimensional calculus to find the absolute maximum on the closed triangle region. I find that the smallest possible $K$ is 1 in this case(Actually, it is at the point $z= \frac{1}{2} + i \frac{1}{2})$. I am not sure if this is true since the closed triangle region is not closed, so not compact. So I am not sure the method of finding absolute maximum in multivriate calculus can be applied here.

Can anyone recommend ?

Comment: It can't be $K = 1$. Since we always have $1-\lvert z\rvert \leqslant \lvert 1-z\rvert$, the quotient is bounded below by $1$. For a set $S$ where $K = 1$ is a possible choice, we must have equality $1-\lvert z\rvert = \lvert 1-z\rvert$ for all $z\in S$. That implies $S\subset [0,1]$. For $z = \frac{1}{2} + \frac{i}{2}$, we have $\lvert z\rvert = \lvert 1-z\rvert = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$, and hence $$\frac{\lvert 1-z\rvert}{1-\lvert z\rvert} = \frac{1/\sqrt{2}}{1-1/\sqrt{2}} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}-1} = \sqrt{2}+1.$$

Comment: So you mean K should be $\sqrt{2}+1$

Comment: At least. You need to check whether the quotient can attain a larger value somewhere on the triangle.

Comment: Is the way to figure $K$ relying on the fact that $K$ depends on only $z_1, z_2$ and the triangle inequality $||a|-|b|| \leq |a-b|$ which implies that the smallest $K$ is when the equality holds.

Comment: If we call the triangle $\Delta$, then what you're looking for is $$\sup_{z\in \Delta\setminus \{1\}} \frac{\lvert 1-z\rvert}{1-\lvert z\rvert}.$$ You can use some geometric considerations to reduce the set of $z$ you need to consider.

Comment: Ok, I will try it. If I need further suggestion, I might ask again. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: @DanielFischer I am not sure, but I guess that what you mean by geometric is that it is suffice to consider just the upper half of the triangle (the half piece over x-axis). I cannot predict what is going on but the point on $(\frac{3}{4},\frac{1}{4})$ might give relatively maximun. Anyway, about 10 points I try is less than $\sqrt{2} + 1$ which is at $z_1$. Other points on the straight line $x = \frac{1}{2}$ , $-1/2 \leq y \leq 1/2$ cannot exceed $\sqrt{2} + 1$ since according to the equation $\frac{|1-z|}{1-|z|} = \frac{\sqrt{1+4y^2}}{2-\sqrt{1+4y^2}}$

Comment: If I fix $x_0$, then in each line $x=x_0$ and $0 \leq y \leq 1-_0$, it seems that the max $y$ give the max value, so for each fix $x_0$, I need to look at $y$ on the line $y = 1-x$, which connecting the points $\frac{1}{2} + i \frac{1}{2}$ and 1.

Comment: The conjugation-invariance is one part. Also, consider the circular arcs $\lvert 1-z\rvert = \rho$ to see you need only look at the line segment between $1$ and $z_1$.

Comment: @DanielFischer So I guess that $\sqrt{2} + 1$ is the $K$ I am looking for. But it is just a guess and I think I am not fully understand the problem that I can give a rigorous proof of this. Can you suggest what should I do ? Thank you very much

Comment: Conjugation-invariance ? Line segment between 1 and $z_1$ ? Do you mean the line $y = 1-x$, $\frac{1}{2} \leq x <1. $

Comment: The quotient $\frac{\lvert 1-z\rvert}{1-\lvert z\rvert}$ doesn't change when you conjugate $z$, that's the conjugation-invariance. And yes, exactly that line, or line segment.

Comment: Ok. I now reach that , in order to find such the smallest $K$, considering only the point on $y = 1-x, 1/2 \leq x < 1$ is enough. On that line, I believe that the point $z_1$ give the maximum, which is important for determining $K$. However, to be more precise in showing this is actually the case, I try to substitute $y = 1-x$ and find critical points, or showing that the function is decresing on the line. Anyway, since the function involves square root and fractions, it is not successful. Any final suggestion for this ?  Sorry for my silliness.

Comment: Write $z = 1 - r e^{-i\pi/4}$ and look at the reciprocal $\frac{1-\lvert z\rvert}{\lvert 1-z\rvert}$. That makes things a bit easier since you then have a simple denominator.